# Loop through json object and return summarized result

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem with calculating json object and returning average result.

this is my json object

```
var testJson = [{
                "1": "0.038728952407837",
                "2": "0.034420967102051",
                "3": "0.034113883972168",
                "4": "0.033237934112549",
                "5": "0.033545017242432",
                "6": "0.033923149108887",
                "7": "0.033990859985352",
                "8": "0.033454895019531",
                "9": "0.033518075942993",
                "10": "0.033759117126465",
                "11": "0.033965826034546",
                "12": "0.03358006477356",
                "13": "0.033926010131836",
                "14": "0.033300876617432",
                "15": "0.033140897750854",
                "16": "0.033447027206421",
                "17": "0.033830165863037",
                "18": "0.033417940139771",
                "19": "0.033578157424927",
                "20": "0.032893180847168",
            }]
```

And this is my code

```
var arr = testJson[0];
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  //loop through the array
    total += arr[i];  //Do the math!
}
console.log(total)
```

and the output of this result is just concatenated string

```
0.0387289524078370.0344209671020510.0341138839721680.0332379341125490.0335450172424320.0339231491088870.0339908599853520.0334548950195310.0335180759429930.0337591171264650.0339658260345460.033580064773560.0339260101318360.0333008766174320.0331408977508540.0334470272064210.0338301658630370.0334179401397710.0335781574249270.0328931808471680.0339531898498540.0339729785919190.0338070392608640.0332689285278320.0333919525146480.033372879028320.0353031158447270.0355949401855470.0359919071197510.036854982376099
```

So, where am I failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the type into float. Since all the variable in the json are string. So when you use adding functionality it works like string concatination. So parse into float before you add. like
**total += parseFloat(arr[i]);**
`for (var key in arr) {
       if (arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         total += parseFloat(arr[key]);
       }
     }
     console.log(total);`

Comment: returned result is 0

Answer (score 3):

It's a type conversion problem. Your values on `testJson` are strings. And `string1 + string2` concats these two strings and result in new string. You should parse this value as Float using `parseFloat` function.

```
if(!Object.values){Object.values=obj=>Object.keys(obj).map(key=>obj[key])}

var arr = Object.values(testJson[0]);
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  //loop through the array
    total += parseFloat(arr[i]);  //Do the math!
}
console.log(total)
```

**Second Alternative;**

```
if(!Object.values)Object.values=obj=>Object.keys(obj).map(key=>parseFloat(obj[key]))
var total = 0;
Object.values(testJson[0]).forEach(function(val){total += val});
```

The code line I used,

```
if(!Object.values)Object.values=obj=>Object.keys(obj).map(key=>parseFloat(obj[key]))
```

is ***polyfill***.

> ***From Wikipedia;***
>   In web development, a polyfill is code that implements a feature on
>   web browsers that do not support the feature. Most often, it refers to
>   a JavaScript library that implements an HTML5 web standard, either an
>   established standard (supported by some browsers) on older browsers,
>   or a proposed standard (not supported by any browsers) on existing
>   browsers. Formally, "a polyfill is a shim for a browser API".[1]

Comment: I don't know why but result is 0

Comment: I see, problem is that we're trying to get length of object. It returns undefined. You can iterate over your object using forEach method or convert this object to value array. _Updated code according to that_

Answer (score 1):

Use parseFloat.

```
var arr = testJson[0];
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  //loop through the array
    **total += parseFloat(arr[i]);  //Do the math!**
}
console.log(total)
```

Comment: Or use Number  Function.  total += Number(arr[i]);

Comment: Or just `total+= +arr[i]`.

Comment: I don't know why but result is 0

Answer (score 1):

```
var key, total = 0;
var testJson = [{
            "1": "0.038728952407837",
            "2": "0.034420967102051",
            "3": "0.034113883972168",
            "4": "0.033237934112549",
            "5": "0.033545017242432",
            "6": "0.033923149108887",
            "7": "0.033990859985352",
            "8": "0.033454895019531",
            "9": "0.033518075942993",
            "10": "0.033759117126465",
            "11": "0.033965826034546",
            "12": "0.03358006477356",
            "13": "0.033926010131836",
            "14": "0.033300876617432",
            "15": "0.033140897750854",
            "16": "0.033447027206421",
            "17": "0.033830165863037",
            "18": "0.033417940139771",
            "19": "0.033578157424927",
            "20": "0.032893180847168",
        }]
(testJson || []).forEach(function(obj){
    for(key in obj ){
       total += parseFloat(obj[key], 10);
    }
});
```